# How to find rows of one dataframe in another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas dataframes `df1` and `df2`. I need to select indices of rows in `df1`, whose (specific) column values are included in `df2`.

This is my code:

```
selected_rows = []

for i, rowi in df1.iterrows():
  for j, rowj in df2.iterrows():
    if (rowi['COL1']==rowj[COL1']) & (rowi['COL2']==rowj['COL2']):
      selected_rows.append(i)
```

The problem is that `df1` is large, and the nested for.loop takes a lot of time. Is there any alternative solution, e.g. using masks?

Sample data:

```
data1 = [['Alex',10,1],['Bob',12,1],['Clarke',13,4]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1,columns=['COL1','COL2','COL3'])

data2 = [['Ted',10],['Bob',12],['Clarke',13]]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2,columns=['COL1','COL2'])
```

The expected answer is: rows 1 and 2 (staring the count from 0).

Comment: please provide some sample input data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
mask = (df1[['COL1','COL2']].isin(df2[['COL1','COL2']])).all(axis=1)
df1[mask]

     COL1  COL2  COL3
1     Bob    12     1
2  Clarke    13     4

selected_rows  = list(df1[mask].index)
[1, 2]
```

Comment: Thanks, cool! Given `selected_rows`, how can I get them from `df1`? `df1.loc[selected_rows]`?

Comment: However this will generate a list of numpy arrays

Comment: This code gives the same result in the specific example but it is not the same as the 2 nested for loops I think. If you swap the 10 with 12 in data1, then the output is different.

Comment: @luigigi Yep, not it looks good. Your method is the best by far, upvoted

Comment: This solution is equivalent to the OP's nested loops only if the number of rows are the same in `df1` and `df2`, and the indices match between matching rows. e.g., If the input example in the OP's code were `data1 = [['Alex',10,1],['Bob',12,1],['John',10,4],['Clarke',13,4]]`, the expected result - as per the nested loops - would be `[1, 3]`, but this solution gives `[1]`.

Comment: Hello, when I did this with my data, i got the error in the line df1[mask].

   2390     # key might be object-dtype bool, check_array_indexer needs bool array

IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).

Answer (score 2):

Here you have some possibilities with the timing.

Here's the input dataframes:

```
np.random.seed(42)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'COL1':np.random.randint(0,30,100), 'COL2':np.random.randint(0,30,100)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'COL1':np.random.randint(0,30,100), 'COL2':np.random.randint(0,30,100)})
```

@Fluxy method:

```
%%timeit
selected_rows = []

for i, rowi in df1.iterrows():
    for j, rowj in df2.iterrows():
        if (rowi['COL1'] == rowj['COL1']) & (rowi['COL2'] == rowj['COL2']):
            selected_rows.append(i)
```

result:

```
693 ms ± 8.46 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

@FBruzzesi method:

```
%%timeit
selected_rows = []

for j, rowj in df2.iterrows():
    selected_rows.append(df1[(df1['COL1'] == rowj['COL1']) & (df1['COL2'] == rowj['COL2'])].index.values)

# Convert to list of numbers
selected_rows = [np.asscalar(x) for x in selected_rows if len(x)]
selected_rows
```

result:

```
87.3 ms ± 1.76 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

My suggestion (still not optimal):

```
%%timeit
selected_rows = [index for index, row in enumerate(df1[['COL1', 'COL2']].values.tolist())
                    if row in df2[['COL1', 'COL2']].values.tolist()]
```

result:

```
60.4 ms ± 1.92 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

The @luigigi method is the best by far:

```
%%timeit

mask = (df1[['COL1','COL2']].isin(df2[['COL1','COL2']])).all(axis=1)
selected_rows  = list(df1[mask].index)
```

result:

```
2.91 ms ± 238 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution will cycle only once and generate a list of integers. The only problem may occur if a row in `df2` matches with more than one in `df1`

```
selected_rows = []

for j, rowj in df2.iterrows():
    selected_rows.append(df1[(df1['COL1']==rowj['COL1']) & (df1['COL2']==rowj['COL2'])].index.values)

# Convert to list of numbers
selected_rows = [np.asscalar(x) for x in selected_rows if len(x)]
```